# Creating a MySQL instance on Cloudbees Jenkins for running tests

Tags: cloudbees

we am using Jenkins hosted on Cloudbees for building our Github hosted code base. We would like to run an Integration Test pipeline for each build. For that, we need to create a MySQL DB before running the integration tests on Jenkins. Is there an easy way to create a MySQL DB as part of a Job in Jenkins, on Cloudbees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the [CloudBees DEV@cloud MySQL guide](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/MySQL).

It covers configuring and starting a MySQL server that runs inside the build process.

A persistent MySQL server is typically more troublesome as you would need to clear out the tables prior to each test run.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to have worked! Now I am trying to figure out how to change the default password of MySQL on CloudBees -- which is currently root and blank password. Will post a separate question.